# `Settings` tab is missing in OpenERP-7

Tags: openerp-7

In OpenERP application `Settings` tab is missing, how do I get back this tab and I am using OpenERP-7.

Answer (score 0):

You need to checkout access right of the User. Login with Admin User or any other User who can see the all list of Users. And open that User which don't see the `Setting` tab.

On User form view has `Access Rights` page. It has `Application => Administration` selection field. That might be empty.

So select Access Rights or Settings to `Application => Administration`

Save record and now login out with Admin and login with that updated User. You will see their `Setting` tab.

Comment: but, `settings` tab is missing for my admin user also.

Comment: okay that login with another user who can see all list of Users and than update admin record.